# Need a simple "Hello World" example using the Webkit library in Python

Tags: python, webkit

Does anyone know of a simple "Hello World" example for using the Webkit library in Python? I have a GTK window, and inside I want to put Webkit.

With Python/mozembed (Mozilla/Gecko), this is simple:

```
mozembed = gtkmozembed.MozEmbed()
mozembed.load_url('http://google.com/')
```

..and I have already created my browser, how do I do this with WebKit?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you check the [Python bindings for the WebKit GTK+ port](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/). In one of the directory there are demos on how to use it, including a browser: python demos/tabbed_browser.py

You could check also the slides of a FOSDEM by Alp Toker on [WebKit GTK+](http://www.atoker.com/webkit/webkitgtk-fosdem08.pdf) (pdf) Developing hybrid Web/GTK+ rich internet applications.

```
import gtk 
import webkit 

view = webkit.WebView() 

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow() 
sw.add(view) 

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.add(sw) 
win.show_all() 

view.open("http://w3.org/") 
gtk.main()
```

That should give you good hints for starting.

Comment: FYI, this appears to use WebKit1 whereas WebKit2 is more recent and has significant rendering and performance improvements. I know it's just a hello world example, but you may have better luck using python-gobject and importing Webkit2.

Answer (score 8):

Now with WebKitGtk2

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('WebKit2', '4.0')

from gi.repository import Gtk, WebKit2

window = Gtk.Window()
window.set_default_size(800, 600)
window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

scrolled_window = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
webview = WebKit2.WebView()
webview.load_uri("https://google.cl")
scrolled_window.add(webview)

window.add(scrolled_window)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: According to the [WebKit2 documentation](https://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkit2gtk/2.5.1/WebKitWebView.html#WebKitWebView.description), you don't need a separate scrolled window: 

"Note that WebKitWebView is scrollable by itself, so you don't need to embed it in a GtkScrolledWindow."

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is [webview](https://pywebview.flowrl.com), which uses WebKit as its base:

```
import webview # you need to install it with pip install webview
webview.create_window("Test",html="<h1>Hi</h1>")
webview.start()
```