# A simple webkit window limited to one URL

Tags: python, webkit, gtk

I want create a python script for run a Gtk window with a WebKit session limited to one URL. i.e. something like [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) or the old Mozilla Prism. Also, I need support for cookies and https.

Something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647121/860789) is perfect but I need block the access to others URL different to the original.

I'm asking about a python example, but examples in other languages are also useful or examples with other toolkits different to Gtk.

PD: I don't know if the title is good or not for my question, so feel free of to enhance this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to the `WebView`'s [`navigation-policy-decision-requested`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView-navigation-policy-decision-requested) signal and call `policy_decision.ignore()` if the URL is not the one you wish to allow.