# Automatic download from sciencedirect

Tags: python, web-scraping, wget, python-requests

I'm trying to automatically download articles from science direct
for example:

```
url = 'http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811913010240'
```

I can access the articles with my browser without problem, but I have tried using Python 's `requests`, `urllib2` and `mechanize` modules without success. Since I need to download many articles, doing it manually is not an option.

Wget does not work either.

E.g.

```
wget http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811913010240
```

returns:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
```

any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2):

They may not be working because the web server doesn't like the User Agent. Perhaps it is trying to block batch downloading.

If you specify a User Agent with `wget`, it works. To use your example.

```
wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" "https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1053811913010240"
```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't "work" it just pulls down a html page full of javascript without the article content. ScienceDirect probably frown upon people trying to scrape their content and it's probably a TOS violation to do so. That said, you could probably use something like python bindings to WebKitGtk to automatically load pages, connect to the load-status property to get notified when the pages has loaded and retrieve the loaded page. See http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#WebKitWebView--load-status

Comment: also see, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647041/need-a-simple-hello-world-example-using-the-webkit-library-in-python/647121#647121

Answer (score 1):

Heres some code i modified to work from pyscholar.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#author: Bryan Bishop <kanzure@gmail.com>
#date: 2010-03-03
#purpose: given a link on the command line to sciencedirect.com, download the associated PDF and put it in "sciencedirect.pdf" or something
import os
import re
import pycurl
#from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import lxml.html
from StringIO import StringIO
from string import join, split

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091123 Iceweasel/3.5.5 (like Firefox/3.5.5; Debian-3.5.5-1)"

def interscience(url):
    '''downloads the PDF from sciencedirect given a link to an article'''
    url = str(url)
    buffer = StringIO()

    curl = pycurl.Curl()
    curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
    curl.setopt(curl.WRITEFUNCTION, buffer.write)
    curl.setopt(curl.VERBOSE, 0)
    curl.setopt(curl.USERAGENT, user_agent)
    curl.setopt(curl.TIMEOUT, 20)
    curl.perform()
    curl.close()

    buffer = buffer.getvalue().strip()
    html = lxml.html.parse(StringIO(buffer))

    pdf_href = []
    for item in html.getroot().iter('a'):
        if (('id' in item.attrib) and  ('href' in item.attrib) and item.attrib['id']=='pdfLink'):
            pdf_href.append(item.attrib['href'])


    pdf_href = pdf_href[0]
    #now let's get the article title

    title_div = html.find("head/title")
    paper_title = title_div.text
    paper_title = paper_title.replace("\n", "")
    if paper_title[-1] == " ": paper_title = paper_title[:-1]
    re.sub('[^a-zA-Z0-9_\-.() ]+', '', paper_title)
    paper_title = paper_title.strip()
    paper_title = re.sub(' ','_',paper_title)

    #now fetch the document for the user
    command = "wget --user-agent=\"pyscholar/blah\" --output-document=\"%s.pdf\" \"%s\"" % (paper_title, pdf_href)
    os.system(command)
    print "\n\n"

interscience("http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0163638307000628")
```

Comment: Try not to only give code, but explain it so that other users can not only use it, but learn from it.